# Can't create Anaconda enviornment. Stuck at solving Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal, geo

i am trying to create a conda enviornment but it alwas stuck at solving envrironment. i have installed fresh copy of lateset ubuntu. i also tried several previos versions of ubuntu and also tried with several previos versions of anaconda.
i am setting up environment by following files shown in attached screenshots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elBql.png)[image]

Previously i had all this setup a year ago. But unfortunately ubuntu crashed a few days ago. I tried to repair ubuntu but no luck. Please anyone help me. I have to complete my thesis work.

Comment: you could try to use Poetry to install all the packages. Then you can pip freeze if you want to see how Poetry solved the dependencies and try that maybe with your setup. Or just continue using Poetry. Maybe it helps

Comment: never heared about Poetry package manager. I'll check and try. thanks